# why my uv maps are deforming

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Note that this uv was way worse earlier. Seamingly smooth perfect squares warp and mangle unless i make more cuts than it seems like it should need.

Ok so i have props for my first ever scene for a game. Its a pretty basic set of platforms,  hand rails, and endposts, corner post and what not. I had no issues 3d modeling it. Ive been modeling for over a year now.  But im just starting to look at using my models so im learning UVs. But I cant seem to just get nice clean geometry.  Every thing blows out of proportion strangely.

there are no triangles in this model except for 4 at the bottom face to kill the n-gons. And its really just been beveled and inset to make this shape. and 1 side has been left flat. Most of the problems ive had i would use orthographic and project from veiw. But these wrap around the egde. How do i get clean square uvs from this. Im mostly worried about the top. But the sides also uv'ed to different sizes? There identical. how?

The pictures below are

So after several hours this is the cleanest result i could come up with. everything is some kinda warped, there are identical geometry that have different sizes on the uv map. And the cone for the top is slightly warped and i worked pretty hard on it. Because it was originally mangled.

i added 2 different attempts i would rather attempt 1 work .but i could settle for 2. stretching is ok in the small insets.

notes: i have already
- applied rotation and scale
- removed duplicates
- thought about applying and very heavy deform modifier.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDu9o.png)

[image]

Comment: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Comment: Sorry ray. It was super late last night and i can get better shots this afternoon.

Comment: You aren't expected to wait until the afternoon as you shouldn't do shots altogether, take screenshots instead and include whole editor windows, not cropping only part where UVs are

Comment: shot in the dark; did you apply the size to your object?

Comment: merge duplicate vertices?

Comment: Yes actually. I tried all of the typical fixes. I just got home from work. Give me a sec and ill get proper shots.

Comment: Also Mr Zak. No aggro. But i have a full time job and mouths to feed. The afternoon bearly exsit so please bear with me. Its all i have is mabey an hour or 2 ever other day. I pretty much have 2 jobs and one works 50 hours a week. Im new here so please go easy on me

Comment: @Sphinix We're just teasing. Don't worry, the Blender community is pretty cool. I hope you can slowly optimise your workload though. But that's a topic for chat, not comments.

Comment: no problem. not harm ment. ive been given the welcome tease in several places